# Can't open the "plots" tab in spyder

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

I closed the plot tab in spyder (next to the variables explorer, the help and the files tab) and now I can't open it again. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go to view -> panes -> then select plots